# MS Dynamics 365 sitemap xml failed XSD validation

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

We are using MS Dynamics 365 and we have the following error when trying to update any element of SiteMap in new built in SiteMap editor

> Sitemap xml failed XSD validation with the following error: 'The element 'SiteMap' has invalid child element 'parsererror' in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'. List of possible elements expected: 'Area'.' at line 1 position 39.

Does anyone know what is the problem here?

Comment: You were trying to edit the default sitemap, or a sitemap from a previous instance of CRM (e.g. after an upgrade)?

Answer (score 1):

If you have Field Service installed, then you have probably new area(s), group(s) components within your Sitemap, coming from Field Service?! Try to correct Group Names -> remove Special characters as "&" or replace them with "and" or encode it correctly. You can do this in Sitemap Editor or in XML directly.

Answer (score 0):

In general **Slađana Perić** gives right answer, with one exception. "Special characters " could be in any Groups/Areas/Subareas as Title/Description and even **URL**. So Sitemap Designer will fail, if you have Contact SubArea with URL to some specific view.
Like `/_root/homepage.aspx?etn=contact&viewid={GUID}&viewtype=1039`